# Whats better std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(std::mutex mutex_var); or std::mutex mutex_var.lock();

Tags: c++, mutex

I need to lock operations of a std::map and two boost::multimaps inside a function since we have threads trying to access the function(and thus the maps).

I am planning to use a "std::mutex mutex_var" to protect those variables inside the function which manipulates them. So I have the "std::mutex mutex_var" variable. I am confused between using "mutex_var.lock()" in the beginning of the function and "mutex_var.unlock()" in the end of the function (OR) just use std::lock_guard in just the beginning of the function?

For clarity all the function does is adding things on the mutex. I also understand/thing that we dont need to guard all the places where we try to query the map(since it is only a read operation).

Please let me know the better alternative, and, also please clarify if my thought of reading does not need protection is correct.

TIA

-R

Comment: You should ask one question at a time.

Comment: What happens if an exception is thrown while you have the mutex locked?

Comment: mutex.lock() might be a problem, but I was thinking that std::lock_guard(mutex_var) would be fine, since the stack frame would go away and thus making the lock_guard lose scope thereby releasing the lock. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: "Only a read operation" doesn't make it atomic & if it is not atomic, it is not safe.

Comment: The read operation is looking up the maps using the keys, would that be an operation that can be performed without a lock? It doesnt alter the map in any way. Please let me know if what I thinking is right.

Comment: @codeworks right. mutex.lock() would be a problem unless you are explicitly dealing with it there inside a try-catch. std::lock_guard() lets you handle the exception somewhere up the call stack without the potental of mistakenly leaving the mutex permanently locked.

Comment: @codeworks the read operation is crawling through the map reading stuff, but after it starts & before it ends another thread could lock, change stuff, and unlock - pulling the rug and perhaps even the floor out from under the reading thread's operation

Comment: Wow, yes, i didnt think of that, I agree reading might also need a lock, but that situation might be a very rare case, but its worth it.. also I will introduce a try catch inside the method where I put my mutex lock/unlock.. and i will anyway for safety use lock_guard and still put the try catch there..

Comment: @Avi How do I release the lock when I catch an exception when I am holding the lock, (1) in the case I use mutex_var.lock(); (2) in the case I use std::lock_guard() ?

Comment: @Avi : Also wanted to know what will happen if I return from the function while holding the lock through the call "std::lock_guard l(mutex_var);". Is it that the scope is lost and will release the lock?

Comment: It is the purpose of `std::lock_guard` to lock the mutex (where the `lock_guard` instance is defined) and then to unlock the mutex for you whenever the scope is exited, regardless of via `return` or via an exception. Hence, you do not have to use `try catch` just to unlock a mutex locked with `std::lock_guard`.

Answer (score 2):

You should (almost) **never use** `std::mutex::lock()`, `std::mutex::try_lock()` or `std::mutex::unlock()` directly, always use a `std::lock_guard` or `std::unique_lock` with your `mutex_var`. Because you don't have to write unlock, because they are doing it when they are destroyed. So you can't forget it, even if a exception has been thrown in the mean time. This is called [*RAII*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) and is what you want for modern C++ code

**So `std::lock_guard` is better**

And for

> I also understand/thing that we dont need to guard all the places where we try to query the map

Usually you still have to guard that read operation, because you don't know when someone wants to write. But it depends on your design, the whole problems is known as [readers-writer-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writers_problem) and since you seem to be unaware of that, I assume your design needs locking for all steps.

Answer (score 0):

- With the simple mutex, if all the threads are reading thread, you don't need to lock the resource. But if there are one or more  among the threads writing to the recourse, you need to lock from all threads even the reading ones.
- There is a way to avoid locking resources, when there is no writing threads and lock the resources when the is one writing thread. You need to use a more complex locking mechanism, you should be reading about openforread and openforwrite logic.